# Control not being returned from promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-cognito

I am trying to register a user using AWS Cognito. In the below `class`, the control from the`registerInCognito` is not being returned. I have tried adding return after the failure and success conditions too (aren't reject and resolve of the promise the same?). But nothing worked. When I tried debugging, I figured out that the section where I have commented `<---- The control is unreachable here.` is not being executed. The control itself is in the return function.

```js
export class CompanyCAO {
    // change return type from any to meaningful type
    private poolData;
    private pool_region;
    private userPool;
    private cognitoUser;
    constructor() {
        this.poolData = {
            UserPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
            ClientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID
        }
        this.pool_region = process.env.COGNITO_POOL_REGION;
        this.userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(this.poolData);
    }

    public create(regInfo: Company): Promise < any > {
        return new Promise < boolean > (async(resolve, reject) => {
            this.registerInCognito(regInfo);
        });
    }

    public registerInCognito(regInfo: Company): Promise < boolean > {

        return new Promise < boolean > (async(resolve, reject) => {
            let attributes = process.env.COGNITO_AUTH_ATTRIBUTES!.split(",");
            let attributeValues = Array < string > ();
            let attributesList = Array < any > ();
            for (var attribute in attributes) {
                for (var attributeName in regInfo) {
                    if (((typeof regInfo[attributeName]) != 'object') && (attributes[attribute] == attributeName)) {
                        attributeValues.push(regInfo[attributeName]);
                    } else if ((typeof regInfo[attributeName]) === 'object') {
                        for (var subAttributeName in regInfo[attributeName]) {
                            if (subAttributeName == attributes[attribute]) {
                                attributeValues.push(regInfo[attributeName][subAttributeName]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            for (var index in attributes) {
                attributesList.push(new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserAttribute({
                    Name: attributes[index],
                    Value: attributeValues[index]
                }));
            }
            const randomPassword = this.createRandomPassword();
            console.log(`Password is ${randomPassword}`);
            await this.userPool.signUp(regInfo.Admin.EmailAddress, randomPassword, attributesList, null, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    this.cognitoUser = result.user;
                }
            }).promise().then((value: any) => {
                resolve(true);
            }).catch(error => {
                reject(error);
            })
        });

                       // <---- The control is unreachable here.
    }

    public createRandomPassword() {
        let password = '';
        const alphaCharacters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
        const numberCharacters = '1234567890';
        const specialCharacters = '!@#$%^&**()?/><}{';
        const iterations = 5;
        for (let i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            password += alphaCharacters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphaCharacters.length));
            password += numberCharacters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * numberCharacters.length));
            password += specialCharacters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * specialCharacters.length));
        }
        return password;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is “here”? Comment line is empty.  How did you confirm that? The class is messy, you mixed up callbacks, promise constructor, thens and async functions. You don’t wait for register method in create. Consider cleaning it up. If you use async...await, do not use raw promises and callbacks unless necessary (in this case it isn’t).

Comment: @EstusFlask, thank you for your reply. I will look into it. Also, I just realized that any code in my commented section will not execute as Promise is being returned, and no execution can happen after that.

Comment: `public create(regInfo: Company): Promise < any > {` returns a Promise that is never resolved or rejected - therefore, anything waiting for the create promise to resolve will wait forever - that function should just `return this.registerInCognito(regInfo);` - which seems to make that function rather pointless - it's like having `function fna(v) { return fnb(v); }` - why not just call `fnb` instead of `fna` :p